# Как не дублировать код попапов, футеров, хедеров?

Tags: javascript, html, css

в каждом файле у меня есть хедер и футер
Как не выводить их в разметке на каждой странице? но при этом , чтобы на самой странице они были

типа include file

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно только средствами браузера, без установки чего либо стороннего то только костылить:

1. без js. загружать во фреймы
2. на js. загружать по ajax'y html файлы и вставлять их содержимое в нужные места.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно использовать [posthtml-include](https://www.npmjs.com/package/posthtml-include), он как раз позволяет использовать в html `include`.

Пример подключения:

```html
<div>
  ...
  <include src="./src/components/footer.html"></include>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Я думаю в ответе стоит указать, что это **не стандартный** HTML тег.